# Why does Get-WmiObject fail when run remotely via Invoke-Command?

Tags: powershell, invoke-command, get-wmiobject

I'm attempting to build a simple "get-ProcessInfo.ps1" module to be used with a PowerShell (forensics/IR) framework called Kansa. The command is a simple one liner that calls Get-WMIObject win32_process and pipes it into Select-Object. Then Kansa SHOULD export the data to Csv via the Export-Csv cmdlet. The script runs without issue on my local host, however it fails when run remotely (on windows) via the Invoke-Command cmdlet in Kansa. My error logging shows get-ProcessInfo.ps1 "Cannot find a process with the process identifier ####", for every processID. Other modules run on the remote hosts without issue, so I know I'm authenticating as an admin. Therefore I think I'm running into a permissions error, or possibly an authentication issue with Wmi. I'm running this in a Windows domain, from a Windows box, via a domain admin account.

Kansa GitHub: https://github.com/davehull/Kansa
Kansa Talk: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cQmsT9D0kKI

I've attempted to replicate the WmiObject call as seen in another Kansa module, but this still did not produce data from remote hosts. - https://github.com/davehull/Kansa/blob/master/Modules/Process/Get-ProcsWMI.ps1

I attempted to understand what was happening in the InjectedThreads.ps1 script since it uses WmiObject remotely without issue, but its a bit over my head. From what I could understand, it sounds like WmiObject is "unmanaged" (unauthenticated? / not inheriting Kerberos from PowerShell?) - https://github.com/davehull/Kansa/blob/master/Modules/Process/Get-InjectedThreads.ps1

I've attempted multiple variations of Wmi Authentication, Impersonation and Privileges. Which unfortunately still produces no remote data. - https://blogs.msmvps.com/richardsiddaway/2011/08/04/authentication-impersonation-and-privileges/

Finally, since get-WmiObject is technically deprecated, in favor of Get-CIMInstance, I've attempted multiple variations of the Get-CIMInstance cmdlet.

Here is the code from the module I'm attempting to make, get-ProcessInfo.ps1

```
Get-WmiObject win32_process | Select-Object creationdate,ws,ProcessName,ProcessID,ParentProcessID, @{Name = 'ParentProcessName';Expression = {(Get-Process -Id $_.ParentProcessId).Name}},Path,CommandLine,@{Name = 'ParentProcessPath';Expression = {(Get-Process -Id $_.ParentProcessId).Path}}
```

Expected results should be a list of processes and their related info, which works on my local machine, and returns no data (just errors) when run remotely via the Invoke-Command within Kansa.ps1

Can someone point me in the proper direction with what exactly is happening here, and how I might go about resolving the issue?

*As a note, this scrip is run via WinRM (Invoke-Command) on a remote host, so asking for credentials is out of the question, and so is hard coded credentials.

Comment: Have you tried `Get-CimInstance -ComputerName` directly? No need to get PowerShell remoting involved via `Invoke-Command`.

Comment: I would try to run your code inside another job with explicitly specified credentials: `Invoke-Command { Start-Job { Get-WmiObject ... } -Credential ... } -Credential ...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your computed properties you're assuming that the `ParentProcessId` is always a valid id:

```
@{Name = 'ParentProcessPath';Expression = {(Get-Process -Id $_.ParentProcessId).Path}
```

The [Win32_Process documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-process) states the following:

> It is possible that the process identified by ParentProcessId is terminated, so ParentProcessId may not refer to a running process. It is also possible that ParentProcessId incorrectly refers to a process that reuses a process identifier.

That means that `ParentProcessId` might point to an already terminated process. In that case `(Get-Process -Id $_.ParentProcessId).Path` will trigger an error (because no process for e.g. 528 is found, therefore `(Get-Process -Id $_.ParentProcessId)` will be `$null` and you're trying to call `$null.Name`).

I tested your one-liner on my machine and didn't receive any error as you described above. Therefore I checked how Kansa invokes a given module, which can be found [here](https://github.com/davehull/Kansa/blob/master/kansa.ps1#L703):

```
$Job = Invoke-Command -Session $PSSessions -FilePath $Module -ArgumentList $Arguments -AsJob -ThrottleLimit $ThrottleLimit
```

As you can see your module file gets invoked as a remote job (see the `-AsJob` switch). I asked myself if there could be a difference in error handling when invoking a script block via a background. I found this interesting StackOverflow [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8751187/how-to-capture-the-exception-raised-in-the-scriptblock-of-start-job) stating:

> Using throw will change the job object's State property to "Failed".  ...

Which makes sense because a job can't ignore errors in comparison to the default PowersShell host. So, I wrapped your command to a job (on my local machine):

```
$job =start-job -ScriptBlock { Get-WmiObject win32_process | Select-Object creationdate,ws,ProcessName,ProcessID,ParentProcessID, @{Name = 'ParentProcessName';Expression = {(Get-Process -Id $_.ParentProcessId).Name}},Path,CommandLine,@{Name = 'ParentProcessPath';Expression = {(Get-Process -Id $_.ParentProcessId).Path}}  } 
Wait-Job $job
$result =Receive-Job $job
```

When calling `Receive-Job` I see the following error on the command line:

> Cannot find a process with the process identifier 528.
>   At line:1 char:1
>   + $result =Receive-Job $job
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (528:Int32) [Get-Process], ProcessCommandException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NoProcessFoundForGivenId,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetProcessCommand
>       + PSComputerName        : localhost

I also checked the `$result` for `$null` :

```
> $null -eq $result
True
```

As can be seen above the error mentions `NoProcessFoundForGivenId`, which is self-explanatory. As you can see the error handling depends on how your code gets invoked (either as Job or either on the PowerShell host).

**What can you do?**

You can check if `ParentProcessId` is valid or not. Therefore you've to change your code to:

```
Get-WmiObject win32_process | ForEach-Object {

    # Create a custom object with the given properties. If Select-Object doesn't find given property it'll create an empty `NoteProperty` with the given name
    $processInfo = $_ | Select-Object creationdate,ws,ProcessName,ProcessID,ParentProcessID, ParentProcessPath, ParentProcessName
    $p = (Get-Process -Id $_.ParentProcessId -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) 

    if ($null -ne $p){
        # Parent process exists lets fill up the empty properties
        $processInfo.ParentProcessName = $p.Name
        $processInfo.ParentProcessPath = $p.Path
    }

    $processInfo # Return this value to the pipeline
}
```

There may be a more sophisticated way to perform `$null` checking in the computed property of `Select-Object`, unfortunately, I'm not aware of it.

If we wrap above code in a job, and run it:

```
    $job = start-job -ScriptBlock { Get-WmiObject win32_process | ForEach-Object {
        $processInfo = $_ | Select-Object creationdate,ws,ProcessName,ProcessID,ParentProcessID, ParentProcessPath, ParentProcessName
        $p = (Get-Process -Id $_.ParentProcessId -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) 
        if ($null -ne $p){
            $processInfo.ParentProcessName = $p.Name
            $processInfo.ParentProcessPath = $p.Path
        }

        $processInfo # Return this value to the pipeline
    } 
}

Wait-Job $job
$result = Receive-Job $job
if ($null -ne $result){
    $result
}
else {
    Write-Error "Job with id $($job.Id) failed"
}
```

We'll get all processes without any kind of error.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you very much. This solution worked perfectly.

Comment: Wonderful detail in this answer.  Very helpful.