# Scriptblock exceptions are not returned in object-events

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0, start-job

`Receive-Job` yields no output on `Start-ThreadJob`- or `Start-Job`-jobs, when listening to `Completed` or `Failed` JobState changes with `Register-ObjectEvent`.

$PSVersionTable dump:

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      5.1.17763.2183
PSEdition                      Desktop
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}
BuildVersion                   10.0.17763.2183
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000
WSManStackVersion              3.0
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
```

Steps to reproduce the issue:

```
$job = Start-ThreadJob -ScriptBlock { throw "Error trying to do a task" }

Register-ObjectEvent $job StateChanged -Action {
    Write-Host ('Job #{0} ({1}) changed state: {2}' -f $sender.Id, $sender.Name, $sender.State)
    if (($sender.State -eq 'Completed') -or ($sender.State -eq 'Failed')) {
        Receive-Job $sender
    }
}
```

When waiting for the job with `Wait-Job` (like suggested in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8751271)) the exception returns correctly, but I need a non-blocking approach. If you use `Start-Job` instead of `Start-ThreadJob`, the exception doesn't return in the event-based approach, too.

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: If you add a sleep counter before `throw`, does it change anything? `sleep 5; throw ...`

Comment: Unfortunately not @AbrahamZinala

Comment: I opened an issue at github according to this behavior: https://github.com/PaulHigin/PSThreadJob/issues/66